# Delete Key press History(GetKeyState) C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem when I press some keys with GetKeyState or with GetAsyncKeyState both record the history of pressed keys. so when I have a cin>> here's the keys I pressed.

```
if(GetKeyState('1'))
            {
                //do stuff
                while(GetAsyncKeyState('1'));
            }

            if(GetAsyncKeyState('2'))
            {
                //do other stuff

                while(GetAsyncKeyState('2'));
            }

            if(GetAsyncKeyState('3'))
            {

                cout<<"Did you press 1? (y/n)"<<endl;
                cin>>answ;
                if(answ=='y')
                {
                    //do stuff
                }


                while(GetAsyncKeyState('3'));
            }
```

Here's what I have:

```
Did you press 1?(y/n)

11223_
```

How to remove the history of my key pressed buttons?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: it's a simple counter. when I press 1. it simple add to an integer +1. when 2 to another integer. like: 1. Calls 2. Answered

Comment: These functions are for GUI applications. You call GetKeyState when you get a keyboard input message from a Windows queue. They do not mix well with iostreams.

Answer (score 5):

I actually had this problem before. First of all, you shouldn't be using mixed inputs in console (like "stdio.h" and "conio.h" and "iostream" and "windows"). In your case I would go for windows console (MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx)
But as you may think, I was lazy too, and I made a workaround for that, here's the code:

```
void ClearConsoleInputBuffer()
{
    // If you happen to have any trouble clearing already cleared buffer, uncomment the section below.
    /* keybd_event('S', 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event('S', 0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_BACK, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_BACK, 0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); */
    PINPUT_RECORD ClearingVar1 = new INPUT_RECORD[256];
    DWORD ClearingVar2;
    ReadConsoleInput(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE),ClearingVar1,256,&ClearingVar2);
    delete[] ClearingVar1;
}
```

Now, what it does? When you type characters into the console they are all stored in Console buffer. When you write `cin >> variable;`, you actually get chars not directly from the user, but from the buffer.
Let me give you an example:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "write something";
Sleep(10000);
int input;
cin >> input;
}
```

You will notice, that when you type characters, even when there is no `cin` called, your key presses are stored.

Now imagine what happens, when you press keys without handling them with `cin'. They will stay in buffer. You should avoid such situations. But you can use the code I mentioned above to clear the console buffer before you start (example below):

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

void ClearConsoleInputBuffer()
    {
        PINPUT_RECORD ClearingVar1 = new INPUT_RECORD[256];
        DWORD ClearingVar2;
        ReadConsoleInput(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE),ClearingVar1,256,&ClearingVar2);
        delete[] ClearingVar1;
    }

int main()
{
    cout << "write something";
    Sleep(3000);

    ClearConsoleInputBuffer();

    int a;
    cin >> a;
}
```